# Running a binary freezes deployment pipeline

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I have a simple workflow with two servers. One clones a repository, zips it and transfers the zipped file via `scp` to the other server. The other server is responsible for unpacking the file, building it, killing the currently running binary and then running the freshly built binary in the specified directory.

The problem here is that the pipeline stalls with these steps. **When I comment out the line to run the binary, then the problem is gone.** Here are the files, I am only going to share the parts that I think are relevant:

`deploy_hft_001.yml`:

```
name: Deploy to hft_001
env:
  HOST_NAME: hft_001

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: hft_000
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run deploy script
        run: |
          . deploy_common.sh
          . deploy.sh "${HOST_NAME}"
```

`deploy.sh`:

```
...
echo "-> Removing build directory"
rm -rf ${BUILD_DIR}
echo "-> Killing the running app."
echo ${HOST_PASS} | sudo -S pkill -f ${BINARY_NAME}
echo "-> Killed the running app."
cd ${DEPLOYMENT_DIR}
echo "-> Running the freshly deployed app."
./${BINARY_NAME}
echo "-> Ran the freshly deployed app."
echo "-> Deployment successful to ${HOST_NAME} on folder: ${DEPLOYMENT_DIR}"
exit
echo "-> Bash exited"
EOT
echo "-> After EOT."
```

`deploy_common.sh` file is just a file to import host usernames, IPs and passwords from environment variables in the cloner server.

This is a part of the output in the workflow:

```
...
-> Creating build directory
-> Extracting repository
-> Deleting archive
-> Opening build directory
-> Building project
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hft_001/github-actions/builds/af175d8ae26b19cf5e022e5b2ed19510a00656e2/build
Scanning dependencies of target config_manager
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/epoll_helper.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/file_helper.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/string_helper.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/socket_helper.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/instrument_manager.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/config_manager.dir/src/json_helper.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable config_manager
[100%] Built target config_manager
-> Creating deployment directory
-> Copying binaries into deployment directory
-> Writing deployment information
-> Removing build directory
-> Killing the running app.
-> Killed the running app.
-> Running the freshly deployed app.
I'm a daemon process, please check the output log:
sudo tail -f /var/log/config_manager.log
-> Ran the freshly deployed app.
-> Deployment successful to hft_001 on folder: ~/workspace/deployments/bist_mp_v2.0/config
-> After EOT.
[sudo] password for hft_001:
```

Pipeline stalls probably due to the the fact that it is prompted to provide a `sudo` password for some reason. I am only using `sudo` to `pkill` the app, and I am providing the host password there with `echo` and it works because I observe that app is killed at that line. So, I have no idea why is the runner prompted for a password? Am I missing something here?

Note that the freshly deployed application is a daemon and it runs just fine!

Comment: `deploy.sh` is invoking the executable. You are saying that it's a daemon but it looks like a normal executable blocking the flow until it's finished. Seems like that's what blocks your workflow.

Comment: Running the executable is not the reason I think, you can see that the following echo commands are working

Comment: Yes, I observed the logs that follow. There are no more workflow steps so it's hard to say anything without that. BTW, the script invokes that binary, have you verified if it is still running after the script exits?

Comment: Also, there's an `exit` in there followed by `echo "-> Bash exited"`, is that intentional? How can the logs after that `exit` are printed? Or, was there a subshell in the original script and it's a leftover from there while doing a copy/paste?

Comment: ```echo "-> Bash exited"``` does not print anything, so it is redundant as you say. However ```echo "-> After EOT."``` prints even though we ```exit```ed before it, so that is strange. Binary is up and running when I deploy, however I cannot verify that it still runs when the script exits, since script never really exit. When I kill the app, the script will exit though.

Comment: Right. How do you kill it when the script is still running? What is that `EOT` for? Are you working on some serial data?

Comment: I just login to the server and just issue ```pkill``` to kill it. I honestly do not know about ```EOT```, I had copied from somewhere else.

Comment: By "server", you mean your self-hosted runner (`hft_000`), right? You need to remove the extra bits from your question. Seems like there is redundant information. As far as I understood, that binary runs and blocks the workflow job. And, that is what you are observing. What kind of binary is it? What does it do? Does it block on user's input or some external API input? Please include that information as well.